# nginx: not matching the correct way

Tags: nginx

i have the following nginx configuration

**GIVES WRONG RESULTS**

```
upstream webapp {
    server webapp:8000;
}


upstream db {
    server phppgadmin:80;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    server_name db.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://db;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /staticfiles/;
    }

   location /media {
       autoindex on;
       alias /mediafiles/;
   }

}
```

My ip address of the pc is xx.xx.xx.xx

what I observed is that

`db.xx.xx.xx.xx`  - shows the `db` upstream

and also `xx.xx.xx.xx`  - shows the `db` upstream

**GIVES CORRECT RESULTS**

where  as when i change the order it shows properly

```
upstream webapp {
    server webapp:8000;
}


upstream db {
    server phppgadmin:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /staticfiles/;
    }

   location /media {
       autoindex on;
       alias /mediafiles/;
   }

}



server {
    listen 80;

    server_name db.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://db;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

Now

`db.xx.xx.xx.xx`  - shows the `db` upstream

and `xx.xx.xx.xx`  - shows the `webapp` upstream

**QUESTION**

I am not able to understand in the first case how come `xx.xx.xx.xx` is matched by `server_name db.*;` Or why the second one shows the intended behaviour

**note**

Ofcourse in my `/etc/hosts` i have setup

```
xx.xx.xx.xx app.xx.xx.xx.xx
xx.xx.xx.xx db.xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx selects `server` block by port (with IP, if given) and `Host` header. If there is no match, it uses a block where `default_server` is set. In your case there is no match by `Host` and neither there is a `default_server` so I think it just picked first. Either add `server_name` to the block with the `webapp` upstream or make it a default one:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

Comment: you mean "xx.xx.xx.xx`  is not matched by any. whereas db.xx.xx.xx.xx` get matched. and eventually in first case it pics first.

Comment: @Santhosh Yes, that's what I mean. There's [an article](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) on that, though it does not explain your case.